# Preserving timestamps when extracting .tgz logs

Tags: tar

I have multiple .tgz kernel-panic logs that I must extract from one file. The timestamps for these .tgz files are important. Whenever I use the following:
`tar - zvxf paniclogs.tgz`

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22359 Feb 22 15:03 kernel-panic-20190213020406-3.tgz
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22971 Feb 22 15:03 kernel-panic-20190213020844-2.tgz
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28344 Feb 22 15:03 kernel-panic-20190213101549-1.tgz
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30683 Feb 22 15:03 kernel-panic-20190213154050-0.tgz
```

It extracts the logs but changes the timestamps to the date and time when I extracted them. This is not the case when I use Cygwin. I know there must be a way to extract these logs and preserve the time stamps. Can you please assist? Thank you.

Comment: The tar options --atime-preserve=system keeps tar from changing the atime on a file when creating a tar archive, and the --xattrs will actually write the atime and ctime into the archive, but apparently, there is no direct way to use those times when extracting from the archive (well you could write your own script).

Answer (score 0):

This *cannot be done* with GNU tar. However there is a lesser known utility `star`, developed by Jörg Schilling, which will accomplish exactly what you are after. I will demonstrate how this works.

First we can examine a single file within a test tgz archive and demonstrate its timestamp, which I have highlighted below to make the terminal output perfectly clear:

```
andrew@ilium$ tar -tv --full-time -f test.tgz mp3enc31/readme.txt
-rw-r--r-- sir/inel        937 1998-11-06 00:28:41 mp3enc31/readme.txt
                               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

As you have found when you extract this file in the customary manner with `tar` the access time (and the change time) is altered. Again I have altered the terminal output to easily show this:

```
andrew@ilium~$ tar -xf test.tgz mp3enc31/readme.txt
andrew@ilium~$ stat mp3enc31/readme.txt 
  File: readme.txt
  Size: 937         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 56885505    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  andrew)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2019-02-23 17:13:55.385500219 +1100     <--------------------
Modify: 1998-11-06 00:28:41.000000000 +1100
Change: 2019-02-23 17:13:55.385500219 +1100     <--------------------
 Birth: -
andrew@ilium~$
```

However if we use the `star` utility as `sudo`, (note that sudo is *required* for the ctime modification) you will see that *all* access times are preserved:

```
andrew@ilium~$ sudo star -xza -ctime < test.tgz mp3enc31/readme.txt
star: 62 blocks + 0 bytes (total of 634880 bytes = 620.00k).
andrew@ilium~$ stat mp3enc31/readme.txt 
  File: readme.txt
  Size: 937         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 59377688    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (30076/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: (30000/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 1998-11-06 00:28:41.000000000 +1100     <--------------------
Modify: 1998-11-06 00:28:41.000000000 +1100
Change: 1998-11-06 00:28:41.000000000 +1100     <--------------------
 Birth: -
andrew@ilium~$
```

The `star` man pages advise some *caution* with the `-ctime` option as it can confuse cron, the news system and even slow the system clock. So just be a little careful!

**References:**

- [man pages for star](https://linux.die.net/man/1/star): Documentation for all of the options used above and demonstration of the many other options available.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate the time and effort you put into your answer. I was really hoping for the same results I get when I use Cygwin to perform the same action. Do you have any idea as to why Cygwin can accomplish this using ```tar -xf``` by Ubuntu cannot?

Comment: @RyanGildersleeve Unfortunately I am not familiar at all with Cygwin :(